# How can i accomplish reactive dates

Tags: meteor

I am creating list of messages that shows how long ago the message was sent.

[image: Screenshot]

This is my messages collection

```
Messages = new Mongo.Collection('messages');
Messages.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    created: {
        type: Date
    },
    text: {
        type: String
    }

}));
```

this my my layout

```
{{#each messages}}

            <li class="message">
                    <span class="message-text">{{text}}</span>
                    <span class="message-date">{{timeAgo created}}</span>
            </li>

{{/each}}
```

This is my helper

```
UI.registerHelper('timeAgo', function (context, options) {
    if (context) {
        return moment(context).fromNow();

    }
});
```

**How can i make it so that my helper updates each minute?**
Right now it is not reactive unless I enter a new message or refresh the page.

**UPDATE**

[Meteor-livestap](https://github.com/copleykj/meteor-livestamp/) does exactly this .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to periodically update a variable using meteor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27412743/how-to-periodically-update-a-variable-using-meteor)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your helper to this:

```
Template.registerHelper('timeAgo', function (context, options) {
    Session.get("time");
    if (context) {
        return moment(context).fromNow();
    }
});

Meteor.setInterval(function() {
    Session.set("time", new Date().getTime());
}, 60000);
```

What this does is change `Session.get("time")` every minute, and forces your helper to recalculate. This should ensure the time stays reactive every minute.

Comment: Thank you. Really appreciate it. It does give me a way to accomplish the task now. But then again i feel like its a quick and dirty solution. i don't know. does the job. Thank YOU!