# How to make a Meteor template helper reactive without changing collection data

Tags: meteor

I'm writing a small application that shows live hits on a website. I'm displaying the hits as a table and passing each one to a template helper to determine the row's class class. The idea is that over time hits will change colour to indicate their age.

Everything renders correctly but I need to refresh the page in order to see the helper's returned class change over time. How can I make the helper work reactively?

I suspect that because the collection object's data isn't changing that this is why and I think I need to use a Session object.

Router:

```
Router.route('/tracked-data', {
  name: 'tracked.data'
});
```

Controller:

```
TrackedDataController = RouteController.extend({

  data: function () {
    return {
      hits: Hits.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}})
    };
  }
});
```

Template:

```
{{#each hits}}
  <tr class="{{ getClass this }}">{{> hit}}</tr>
{{/each}}
```

Helper:

```
Template.trackedData.helpers({
  getClass: function(hit) {
    var oneMinuteAgo = Date.now() - 1*60*1000;
    if (hit.createdAt.getTime() > oneMinuteAgo) {
      return 'success';
    } else {
      return 'error';
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I didn't use it but saw it some time ago with answer - Date isn't reactive therefore your helper won't be reactive as well, try using http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_dependency to force rewriting actual date to some variable(maybe session) and then use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get this working though I'm not sure it's the 'right' way to do it. I created a function that is called every second to update `Session` key containing the current time. Then, in my helper, I can create a new `Session` key for each of the objects that I want to add a class to. This session key is based upon the value in `Session.get('currentTime')` and thus updates every second. `Session` is reactive and so the template updates once the time comparison condition changes value.

```js
var updateTime = function () {
  var time = Date.now();
  Session.set('currentTime', time);
  setTimeout(updateTime, 1 * 1000); // 1 second
};
updateTime();


Template.trackedData.helpers({

  getClass: function(hit) {
    var tenMinutesAgo = Session.get('currentTime') - 10*1000,
        sessionName = "class_" + hit._id,
        className;
    className = (hit.createdAt.getTime() > tenMinutesAgo) ? 'success' : 'error';
    Session.set(sessionName, className);
    return Session.get(sessionName);
  }
});
```

### Update

Thanks for the comments. The solution I ended up with was this:

**client/utils.js**

```js
// Note that `Session` is only available on the client so this is a client only utility.

Utils = (function(exports) {

  return {

    updateTime: function () {
      // Date.getTime() returns milliseconds
      Session.set('currentTime', Date.now());
      setTimeout(Utils.updateTime, 1 * 1000); // 1 second
    },

    secondsAgo: function(seconds) {
      var milliseconds = seconds * 1000; // ms => s
      return Session.get('currentTime') - milliseconds;
    },
  };

})(this);

Utils.updateTime();
```

**client/templates/hits/hit_list.js**

```
Template.trackedData.helpers({
  getClass: function() {
    if (this.createdAt.getTime() > Utils.secondsAgo(2)) {
      return 'success';
    } else if (this.createdAt.getTime() > Utils.secondsAgo(4)) {
      return 'warning';
    } else {
      return 'error';
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Can anyone advise as to a better way? Thanks!

Comment: Your solution is the way to go, although you don't need to set any session in your helper. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588583/how-can-i-accomplish-reactive-dates/27589150#27589150).