# Momentjs doesn't update time .fromNow()

Tags: meteor

When I load the page all is working fine, but: why momentjs doesn't update the time?
If I insert a new post is inserted, momentjs doesn't update the *a few seconds ago* text with *a minute ago*.

This is what I'm doing.

I've added the `momentjs:moment` package

Registered the helper

```js
UI.registerHelper('timeAgo', function(datetime) {
    return moment(datetime).fromNow();
});
```

In the Template

```html
<template name="postItem">
    <li>
      {{text}} - {{timeAgo createdAt}}
    </li>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

The output is

```
Hi! - a few seconds ago
Hello! - 23 minutes ago
```

Answer (score 6):

The date isn't a reactive variable so it won't refresh when the time difference changes.

You can make it reactive by forcing it to recalculate every minute (or a custom interval):

```
UI.registerHelper('timeAgo', function(datetime) {
    Session.get('time');
    return moment(datetime).fromNow();
});

setInterval(function() {
    Session.set("time", new Date())
}, 60000); //Every minute
```

This will force the helper to redraw the value for time every minute.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivity

Following are only reactive sources

```
These Meteor functions run your code as a reactive computation:

Templates
Tracker.autorun
Blaze.render and Blaze.renderWithData


And the reactive data sources that can trigger changes are:

Session variables
Database queries on Collections
Meteor.status
The ready() method on a subscription handle
Meteor.user
Meteor.userId
Meteor.loggingIn



In addition, the following functions which return an object with a stop method, if called from a reactive computation, are stopped when the computation is rerun or stopped:

Tracker.autorun (nested)
Meteor.subscribe
observe() and observeChanges() on cursors
```

In your example you're just displaying value(date),

It is like displaying some name that's it you are not displaying reactive source,

If you display reactive source then it will be automatically changed when the value changes.

If you want to create your own reactive source look at here http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar_pkg

**EDIT**

Coming to the solution

Try this package `https://atmospherejs.com/copleykj/livestamp`

I haven't used it personally though. Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for the tip for `livestamp`, easily got it running and it works like a charm. I just pulled it in from https://mattbradley.github.io/livestampjs/ and made my own global helper.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how reacitvity works. No reactive value change, so there are no recomputations. The easiest solution is to make time reactive. See this answer: [How can i accomplish reactive dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588583/how-can-i-accomplish-reactive-dates/27589150#27589150)